# connection is going to be closed but there is an active transaction

Tags: database-connection, warnings, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, deprecation-warning

ihave script adlinkfly after iset settings and save he give me blank page
igo to error log ifound
Warning: The connection is going to be closed but there is an active transaction
the problem is when i click save in settings he give me blank white page

Comment: Don't use nulled version buy it from official developer

Comment: Please check your spelling, there is no way you can believe that the several words with "i" at the beginning really exist in English. While you are at it, fix some other minimal language agreements, like capitalisation and a minimum of punctuation.